# Covariant Derivative Formula Proof from Barrett O'Neil's Elementary Differential Geometry

Tags: geometry, derivatives, differential-geometry

If $\{E_1,E_2,E_3\}$ is a frame field and $W=$ $\sum_i f_iE_i$

Prove the covariant derivative formula;

$$\nabla_VW = \sum_j\biggr(V[f_i]+\sum_i f_i\omega_{ij}(V)\biggr)E_j  $$

(Where $V[f_i]$ is directional derivative of scalar f and $\omega$ is connection form for frame field.)

Is there any mistake about formula? Directional derivatives are independent from j? In addition, assistant have make a proof such as $$\nabla_VW = \sum_j\biggr(V[f_j]+\sum_i f_i\omega_{ij}(V)\biggr)E_j  $$ in our application class. Which one is true?

Summary of what he did :

$$\nabla_VW = \nabla_V (\sum_i f_iE_i) = \sum_iV[f_i]E_i+\sum_i \sum_j f_i\omega_{ij}(V)E_j  $$

and he interchanged i and j at $ \sum_iV[f_i]E_i $ as $ \sum_jV[f_j]E_j $ then he got 
$$\nabla_VW = \sum_j\biggr(V[f_j]+\sum_i f_i\omega_{ij}(V)\biggr)E_j  $$

Comment: There is a typo in the original formula. It should indeed be $V[f_j]$ (the index $i$ was changed to $j$, but not quite everywhere).

Comment: @TedShifrin As I understand the second one is true (which is proved in our application class), isn’t it sir?